# Probability of rolling a cuboid dice

Tags: probability, physics, dice

It's easy to count the probability of events on a regular dice because we know the probabilities ($P(1)$, $P(2)$, $P(3)$, $P(4)$, $P(5)$, $P(6)$) of all the basic outcomes ($P(i)=\frac{1}{6}$).

[image]

But... **Is there any (simple) way how to determine the probabilities of basic outcomes of a cuboid dice?**
Let's suppose for example a cuboid of sizes 1 cm, 1.1 cm, 1.2 cm...

Comment: The only way is to throw it a gazillion times and count the outcomes.

Comment: You might be able to derive something from the areas of the faces, center of mass, and moment of inertia. Although it probably could not be called simple.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you throw it. A simple model would be to find the ratio of the area of one side and the total surface area of the cuboid.

Comment: @TonyK It's actually a thing I expected a physicist would do - to have cuboids where one size varies, perform a gazillion throwings for each and then deduce some interpolating function...

Comment: It doesn't just depend on the die itself - it also depends crucially on the coefficients of friction and restitution of the surface it's thrown on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Diaconis, Holmes, and Montgomery](http://comptop.stanford.edu/u/preprints/heads.pdf) have shown that when you look closely at the actual dynamics, taking angular momentum, etc., into account, even a coin toss is rather complicated.

Comment: I found out that when math meets reality, everything becomes rather complicated and unclear. That's why I prefer math over physics. Real life: _Can you measure the length of this pencil to 1000 decimal places? Can you ride a bike exactly 20 MPH? Can you wake up at 7 o'clock? Can you split (something) into two equal halves? No, I'm sorry, I can't do any of those._

Answer (score 4):

I once made some tests with this seven-sided die, which was claimed to land on each side with an equal probability:

[image: seven-sided die]
<sup>Source: [Wiki Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:D07.jpg).</sup>

It turned out that I could easily influence the probability of the outcome (more precisely the probabilty that it lands on a certain type of side) with the throwing technique, for example by giving the die a higher angular momentum when throwing it.

An extreme and illustrative example for this are [tippe tops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippe_top): If thrown without any momentum or angular momentum (i.e., if just dropped) from a small height and with a random starting orientation, they have a non-zero probablity of coming to rest in a “stem-down” position (at least some of them). When the angular momentum is very high in the otherwise identical situation, they almost certainly assume their characteristic rotation after some time and thus come to rest in a “stem-up” position.

The only way that the probability of a resting position does not depend on the initial angular momentum is that all resting positions are indistinguishable in respect to the inertia tensor (which is certainly not true for a true cuboid). Though I cannot prove it right now, I am very certain, that this is true for face-uniform solids (Platonic solids, Catalan solids, …), i.e., solids, whose faces are indistinguishable, only.

Analogue considerations should apply for other parameters like friction between die and surface and initial momentum and height. Thus, we have to agree on some distribution for these parameters to make a statement about the probabilities of the outcomes. And there arguably is no straightforward way to so, as for example choosing a uniformly distributed angular momentum would require a uniform distribution on $ℝ$.

While no direct answer to your question, this should illustrate why even defining the probabilities you seek is a problem on its own and why calculating them would be very difficult.

Comment: Funny fact: When I say »this seven-sided die«, I happen to refer to that exact die.

Answer (score 0):

The system can be best modeled by creating an analogy with thermodynamics or considering an integral over the solid angle.  Either way this question that has been answered elsewhere:

http://www.riemer-koeln.de/mathematik/quader/cuboid.metrika.pdf

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41297/how-to-determine-the-probabilities-for-a-cuboid-die